# Recusion - calculating sum of digits in a mixed string. (homework dead end)

Tags: java, recursion

I've got into a dead end while trying to fix some lines
in my code.

The task is writing a Recursion function which takes a string and calculating
the sum of the numbers in it.

For example -

```
input - "5a-f5-11"
output- The numbers are 5, 5 and 11, therefore the sum is 21.
```

the Catch in this task is to sum numbers that are more than one digit.
(11 in our case)

I have not planned to use Char arrays or anything, but working with strings in some lines made it difficult.

My code doesn't compile so far but i'm sure the logic is in the right spot - (i made a helper function, which means its not the final function but its doing the main work).

```
public static int  sumNumbersInText(String str, int i, String subStr, int sum) {

    if(str.length() >= i) return sum;

    char[] array = new char[str.length()];
    str.getChars(0, str.length(), array, 0);

    char oneStr = array[i];
    String newSubStr = subStr;
    if(Character.isDigit(oneStr)); //if the new index is not a number and the index before IS a number>
    {

        if(Character.isDigit(subStr));// new index IS a number, therefore will sum up.
        {
            int num = 0;
            sum+=num;
            newSubStr = "";
        }
    }

    else                             
    {
        newSubStr += oneStr;
    }

    return sumNumbersInText(str, i+1, subStr, sum);
}
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon after your if-tests (like the one in `if(Character.isDigit(oneStr));`). They terminate your if-block immediately, causing what you think is the if-block to always run.

Comment: Is the recursion a requirement, or is was that your idea?

Comment: "the Catch in this task is to sum numbers that are more than one digit. (11 in our case)"  It's unclear what should be done here.  Should you find multiple digits and treat them as a **whole number** (11), or add up the digits to get 2?  What if there are more than one multiple digit numbers like in "5a-f5-11-b2-41"?  What would the result be now?

Comment: @Mureinik Its a requirement, lol with for loop its not as challenging.

Comment: @Idle_Mind its quite clear if you didnt miss that - input - "5a-f5-11"
output- The numbers are 5, 5 and 11, therefore the sum is 21.

Comment: Still not clear...the description and the example don't match.  The wording says "sum numbers that are **MORE** than **ONE** digit".  So why are the fives being included?  Also, the multiple digits are not being "summed", they are being concatenated and treated as a whole number.

Comment: I could interpret that as only "sum" the digits in "11" (because they have more than one digit) and get a result of 2.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Well, they simply mean, If there is a number separated by space, or any other Char from the other number, Treat it as a single digit number. But if the number is followed by another number, such as 11 in this example, Treat it as the whole Integer ( 11 ) not 1 + 1. That's why the input of "5a-f5-11" is going to return 21. i could try to simplify it more if you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd approach it:

```
public class AddMultipleDigitsInStringRecursive
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String input = "5a-f5-11";
        System.out.println("Input: " + input);
        int sum = sumDigits(input);
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
    }

    public static int sumDigits(String input)
    {        
        return addDigits(input, 0, "");
    }

    private static int addDigits(String input, int index, String curNumber)
    {
        if(index < input.length())
        {
            int curSum = 0;
            String curChar = input.substring(index, index + 1); // get the current character (as a String)
            if (Character.isDigit(curChar.charAt(0))) // if it's a digit, append it to the current number
            {
                curNumber = curNumber + curChar;
            }
            else // it's not a digit, do we have a number pending?
            {
                if (!curNumber.isEmpty())
                {
                    curSum = Integer.parseInt(curNumber); // convert current number to an Integer
                }
                curNumber = ""; // reset the current number so we can accumulate more digits when they are found
            }   
            // return the sum of the current number (if any) with any other numbers that are found
            return curSum + addDigits(input, index + 1, curNumber); 
        }
        else // reached the end of the string; was there a number pending?
        {
            int curSum = 0;
            if (!curNumber.isEmpty())
            {
                curSum = Integer.parseInt(curNumber);
            }
            return curSum;
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow managed to figure it out, it actually works:

```
public static int sum(String str, int i, String subStr, int sum) {
    if(str.length() <= i) return sum;
    String newSubStr = subStr;
    char oneStr = str.charAt(i);

    if(!Character.isDigit(oneStr)) //if the new index is not a number and the index before IS a number>
    {
        if(isNumeric(subStr))// new index IS a number, therefore will sum up.
        {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(subStr);
            sum+=num;
            newSubStr = "";
        }
    }
    else                             
    {
        String temp = oneStr+"";
        newSubStr += temp;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    return sum(str, i+1, newSubStr, sum);
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `if(isNumeric(subStr))` check.  The only time you appended to that string was in the else block of `!Character.isDigit(oneStr)`, so you only ever appended valid digits, and therefore the string must already be a valid number.  You can simply check to see if "subStr" is **not blank**, and then add that number.

Comment: Using you example input of "5a-f5-11", your code incorrectly returned 10.  Your first line of the recursive function checks to see if you're past the end of the string.  At that point, you need to see if there is a value in "subStr" waiting to be added to the current sum.

Comment: You should make the name of the function and the fourth parameter different; they're both "sum" which can be confusing.  In fact, you don't even need that fourth parameter...it's possible to do it with only the first three (see my solution).

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is one simple way of using recursion to solve the problem.  I used a regular expression to grab the numbers since you didn't indicate that it was not permitted.

```java
   public static int sum(String a) {
      Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d\\d+)").matcher(a);
      if (m.find()) {
         return Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)) + sum(a.substring(m.end()));
      }
      return 0;
   }
```